# CSS calc works with vh but not %

Tags: css

I have the following:

```css
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.navbar-header {
  background: green;
}

.sidebar {
  background-color: #333;
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
  color: #fff;
  position: fixed;
  width: 178px;
  height: 100%;
}

.content {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  height: calc(100% - 150px);
  background-color: #ffffff;
  overflow: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  margin-left: 178px;
}

.footer {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  min-height: 78px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #f6f9fb;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: calc(100% - 178px);
  left: 185px;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar-header">
  header
</div>
<nav class="sidebar">
  sidebar
</nav>

<div class="content">
  content
</div>


<div class="footer">

  footer
</div>
```

But in my project to make the `calc` work I changed `%` per `vh` to make it work, I am sorry I can't provide my local code, but I would like understand why my code just worked with `vh` instead of `%`.

```
height: calc(100vh - 150px);
height: -moz-calc(100vh - 150px);
height: -webkit-calc(100vh - 150px);
```

Comment: It is working. Use a background color on `.content` instead of a thin border to notice it better.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the problem is. The fiddle and snippet work fine in various browsers, and I can't see a difference when I change the % to vh. You should put the line with `calc` after the lines with `-moz-calc` and `-webkit-calc` though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A percentage value for height (also in `calc`) only works if either the parent element has a fixed height, or if all parents, grandparents etc. up to the body (or up to an ancestor with fixed px width) have a percentage height (i.e. no `auto` height).

Comment: The code in the question *does* have a percentage height defined on all parents up to the root element. The `height: calc(100% - 150px);` is actually working.

Answer (score 1):

`vh`is the viewport height, the area where your elements render. Setting your elements to `100vh` is basically telling them to occupy the whole height of your view port.

Using `%` in the other hand is telling your elements to use all the space they need. If your `div`is empty, then your viewport will be empty.